# Toad for Oracle 12.12: What is the difference between Literal and Environment Variable?

Tags: oracle, variables, toad

I am using the variable `&WEIGHT` several times in my SQL code. When I am executing, the following window appears requesting me to set the value of my variable.

[image]

I have two main questions:

1) What is the difference between the Literal and the Environment Variable?

2) The variable `&WEIGHT` is stated several times in the SQL code. This means that all these statements will take the same value is that correct?

Comment: a literal is a costant value  ( a value as  is ) and don't change ..   a (enviroment) variable is symbolic name for store a value  for read and whene necessary for change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Littlefoot's explanation of the literal vs. environment variable is spot on. Regarding your second question you will be prompted for a value for each WEIGHT you have declared using a single ampersand. If you want to enter WEIGHT once and retain the same value for each use then use a double ampersand.

Example 1, prompts for WEIGHT twice.

```
select &WEIGHT, &WEIGHT from dual;
```

Example 2, prompts for WEIGHT once.

```
select &&WEIGHT, &&WEIGHT from dual;
```

The single/double ampersand also applies when you have many statements executed together as a script, <kbd>F5</kbd> shortcut in Toad.

Example 1, prompts for WEIGHT twice, once for each statement.

```
select &WEIGHT from dual;
select &WEIGHT from dual;
```

Example 2, prompts for WEIGHT once, once first time it is encountered and that value is reused for every subsequent statement using &&WEIGHT.

```
select &&WEIGHT from dual;
select &&WEIGHT from dual;
```

See the "Avoiding Unnecessary Prompts for Values" section in the [SQL*Plus user's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#SQPUG015).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

*A substitution variable(`&WEIGHT` here) is a placeholder, just as a variable in a program unit, and useful for performance reasons. Since parsing for execution of the select statement is performed once in this case, while for every literal parsing operation is repeated. So, None of each statement will have the same value for each invoke.*

*Moreover using a literal has vulnerability to sql injection.*

*P.S. For string type of values, single-quoted `'&STR'` substitution variables is used.*

Comment: So this means that I need to set the value for each one them i.e. &WEIGHT (0), &WEIGHT (1), etc. correct?

Comment: @Whitebeard13 exactly, those are all different.

Comment: Despite the fact that the value is always the same?

Comment: @Whitebeard13 Despite the fact that `the variable` is always the same ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Literal is something you enter, manually - for example, `10` as DEPTNO from Scott's tables.

Environment variable is what its name says - lets you pick among TOAD or system variables (such as SYSDATE, PATH, TNSADMIN, etc.).

As of your second question, yes - no matter how many statements you have (SQL or PL/SQL), windows, different connections ... if you use the same WEIGHT variable in all of them, they'll get the same value.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and nice answers. Just to make sure that I understood correctly. In order to ensure that each of the `WEIGHT&` statements takes the same value, I need to set the value for each one them i.e. &WEIGHT (0), &WEIGHT (1), etc.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. Ummm ... no. If you use the same variable in all those queries, then you run the first of them and set variable's value to, say 100. If you run some other query which uses the same variable, the last value (100) will be used as a default (if you want) so you'd just have to press ENTER and run the query and use the same WEIGHT = 100 value. If you want to change it, well - do that - type some other value when prompted.

Comment: By the way, in TOAD, I use colon when working with variables, i.e. `where col = :weight` instead of `where col = &weight`. That will work in SQL Developer as well, but won't work in SQL*Plus.